# CFMessagePort and sandboxing

Tags: macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I am adapting a MacOS application to use sandboxing. It uses a helper application (an exe in the same bundle) that fails when I try calling CFMessagePortCreateRemote with a 'deny mach-lookup' message in the console.

I can see the `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name` entitlement key could solve this, but it is only temporary.

Is there a way to achieve a communication between two apps with a mach port in a sandboxed application?

Errors:

```
let port = CFMessagePortCreateLocal(nil, "XXXYYYZZZZ.MyAppGroupName" as CFString, Callback, nil, nil)
let runLoopSource = CFMessagePortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, port, 0)
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, .commonModes)
```

> *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x14807, name = 'XXXYYYZZZZ.MyAppGroupName'

Answer (score 5):

For both targets app and helper exe :

- Enable sandboxing
- Add a common group prefixed by you teamid

  > Z123456789.com.example.app-group

Name your mach port using your teamID ex :

> Z123456789.com.example.app-group.Port_of_Kobe

[Apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW24)

Comment: Note adding the additional `.Port_of_Kobe` string at the end of the App Group ID when creating the Mach Port string! Very important. You cannot just use your App Group ID.

Answer (score 0):

My call to `CFMessagePortCreateRunLoopSource` was crashing when using the wrong `CFStringRef name` parameter in `CFMessagePortCreateLocal`.

I was using the name of my app group, `XXXYYYZZZZ.MyAppGroupName`.

After reading the Apple documentation, I changed it to `XXXYYYZZZZ.MyAppGroupName.someOtherString` and the crash went away.

> Mach port names must begin with the application group identifier, followed by a period (.), followed by a name of your choosing.
>
> For example, if your application group’s name is `Z123456789.com.example.app-group`, you might create a Mach port named `Z123456789.com.example.app-group.Port_of_Kobe`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW24

Edit:

The following morning, I'm trying to run the same code. This time, I'm getting the crash *with* the same appended `".someOtherString"` that I was using last night. It works fine if I change to some *other* string. This is frustrating, as I have no idea when/how that string becomes invalid.

> #### Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
>
> *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xcd07, name = 'XXXYYYZZZZ.MyAppGroupName.someOtherString'

Edit 2:

I hit the crash again, this time with the new string. The issue is possibly related to running a version of the app from the `/Applications/` folder in addition to a version from my Xcode build folder.

> Port names should generally be unique within the current user context; otherwise, you might run into conflicts.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html