# Cocoa/App Group Interprocess Communication via CFMessagePort

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ipc, sandbox, core-foundation

I'm trying to pass a string (though my real goal is to pass an array) from one macOS app to the other. The receiver app is sandboxed while the sender app is not sandboxed.

I've added an App Group (`DEV_TEAM_ID.com.if.APP_NAME.UNIQUE_NAME`) to both apps.

**In the receiver app**, I have implemented creating the port and runloop:

```
CFMessagePortRef localPort =
    CFMessagePortCreateLocal(nil,
                             CFSTR("DEV_TEAM_ID.com.if.APP_NAME.UNIQUE_NAME"),
                             PortCallBack,
                             nil,
                             nil);

CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource =
    CFMessagePortCreateRunLoopSource(nil, localPort, 0);

CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                   runLoopSource,
                   kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

and the callback, of course:

```
CFDataRef PortCallBack(CFMessagePortRef local, SInt32 msgid, CFDataRef data, void *info) {
     char *message = "Thanks for saying hello!";
     CFDataRef returnData = CFDataCreate(NULL, (const UInt8 *)message, strlen(message)+1);
     printf("here is our received data: %s\n", CFDataGetBytePtr(data));
     return returnData;
}
```

In the **sender app**, I have implemented:

```
CFMessagePortRef remotePort = CFMessagePortCreateRemote(nil, CFSTR("DEV_TEAM_ID.com.if.APP_NAME.UNIQUE_NAME"));
SInt32 messageIdentifier = 1;
CFDataRef messageData = (__bridge CFDataRef)[@"hello, friend." dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SInt32 status = CFMessagePortSendRequest(remotePort, messageIdentifier, messageData, 1000, 0, NULL, NULL);

if (status == kCFMessagePortSuccess)
{
    NSLog(@"success");
}
```

The **receiver** app launches fine, but the **sender** app crashes on this line:

```
SInt32 status = CFMessagePortSendRequest(remotePort, messageIdentifier, messageData, 1000, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

**EDIT:** It seems that `remotePort` is *null*, and is causing the crash
with the following error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
>
> CoreFoundation`**CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER**:
> 0x7fff20707fe0 <+0>:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
> 0x7fff20707fe3 <+3>:  je     0x7fff20707fed            ; <+13>
> 0x7fff20707fe5 <+5>:  pushq  %rbp
> 0x7fff20707fe6 <+6>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
> 0x7fff20707fe9 <+9>:  callq  *0x10(%rdi)
> ->  0x7fff20707fec <+12>: popq   %rbp
> 0x7fff20707fed <+13>: retq
> 0x7fff20707fee <+14>: nop
> 0x7fff20707fef <+15>: nop
> 0x7fff20707ff0 <+16>: nop
> 0x7fff20707ff1 <+17>: nop
> 0x7fff20707ff2 <+18>: nop
> 0x7fff20707ff3 <+19>: nop
> 0x7fff20707ff4 <+20>: nop
> 0x7fff20707ff5 <+21>: nop
> 0x7fff20707ff6 <+22>: nop

I'm not sure why `remotePort` would have a *null* value. I'm using the same port name in both apps.

I've been trying to use code examples and other posts here on Stackoverflow to solve the issue, but I don't understand where I've messed it up. I would greatly appreciate any advice! Thanks!

Posts I've looked at:
https://nshipster.com/inter-process-communication/
[CFMessagePort and sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889186/cfmessageport-and-sandboxing/42683708)
[Theos inter-app communication using mach ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182144/theos-inter-app-communication-using-mach-ports)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to sort this out after reading [Using App Groups for communication between macOS/iOS apps from the Same Vendor](https://www.appcoda.com/app-group-macos-ios-communication/)

The problem was that as of Big Sur (or possibly Catalina), macOS apps using App Groups require a group container to be created in the developer portal. after doing that, you need to reconfigure the code-signing your app to include a provisioning profile. I'm not really sure when this all became a requirement since setting up App Groups isn't really well-documented by Apple. Everything works great after following the steps in the above linked article.

I was able to get my array passed from one app to another:

```
NSData* myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.runningProcs];
            
CFMessagePortRef remotePort = CFMessagePortCreateRemote(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, CFSTR("group.DEV_TEAM_ID.com.if.APP_NAME.UNIQUE_NAME"));
SInt32 messageIdentifier = 1;
CFDataRef messageData = (__bridge CFDataRef)(myData);
    
SInt32 status = CFMessagePortSendRequest(remotePort, messageIdentifier, messageData, 1000, 0, NULL, NULL);

if (status == kCFMessagePortSuccess)
{
      NSLog(@"success");
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to call `CFRelease` on your `remotePort`?